# Multiple Auto Play Vimeo Videos, but only one auto plays

Tags: vimeo, autoplay

I've been searching the forums here for an answer to this, but each solution seems a bit off from what I'm actually experiencing.

Is there a way to make **all iframe vimeo videos auto play**? We’re using vimeo vids (muted) in place of resource glutton GIFs, but it looks like only one video auto plays, while the others do not, even though they’re all set to auto play and loop.

It’s also odd that it chooses randomly which video it’s going to auto play, and which ones it doesn’t.

Thanks for your suggestions!

https://stable.stable-demos.com/what-we-do/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the parameter `?background=1`. As stated [here](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-and-chromeless-videos)...

> Adding this parameter will have the following effects:
>
> 1. All player toggles and elements will be turned off (including the play/pause button!)
> 2. The video will automatically loop.
> 3. The video will be set to autoplay.
> 4. The video will be muted.

All videos marked with this tag will also play concurrently ([example](https://parkerschmidtmedia.com/op6DTEueO0p5vdzFtzs8)).

Unfortunately, autoplay can be finicky on mobile due to data concerns: [autoplay will not work in Safari or Chrome on iOS if low power mode is enabled](https://forum.webflow.com/t/html5-video-does-not-autoplay-on-ios-anymore/54029/6). There are workarounds to this, but you may want to hide the videos on mobile anyway to improve performance. More information on Autoplay Restrictions and Workarounds can be found [here](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos).

Comment: Thank you kindly! This was exactly what we were looking for!

Comment: My pleasure. It should be noted that `?autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1&autopause=0` has the same effect as `?background=1`. In my opinion however, the latter is the cleanest and easiest way to achieve a GIF like state

Answer (score 4):

You should make sure those Vimeo embed codes contain the `autopause=false` parameter. If you have multiple Vimeo videos embedded on a page, only one video will be playable at a time.

Each embed code should look like this:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?autopause=false" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Autopause and other player parameters are documented here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters